How to Implement Dynamic Redirection Logic in GoRouter Package in Flutter?
I'm currently working with the GoRouter package in Flutter for navigation in my app. I need to implement dynamic redirection logic based on certain conditions, but I'm unsure how to achieve this within the package's framework.
Specifically, I want to implement the following logic in the redirect function of the GoRouter:

Retrieve the current path from the GoRouterState object.
Find the widget corresponding to this path.

However, the GoRouter package doesn't seem to have built-in support for such functionality.
Here's the code snippet demonstrating what I wish to achieve:
redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) async {
  String? path = state.path;
  // Find the widget corresponding to the path
  Widget? widget = state.findWidgetByPath(path); // I needed a function like this

  return state.path;
},

I would appreciate any ideas on how to achieve this.
Thank you

The widget returned by _findWidgetByPath is it the one created by the pageBuilder of the GoRoute? What does the protectedByRoute funciton do internatlly, is it a static funcion of the widget (stateless vs stateful?)?

@pcba-dev the findWidgetByPath is a function I wish to get from the GoRouterState

What do you mean by the widget corresponding to the path?
